# Neo4j index for full text search

Tags: indexing, neo4j, full-text-search, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on neo4j database version 2.0.I have following requirements :

Case 1. I want to fetch all records where name contains some string,for example if i am searching for Neo4j then all records having **name** Neo4j Data,Neo4j Database,Neo4jDatabase etc. should be returned.

Case 2. When i want to fire field less query,if a **set of properties** is having matching value then those records should be returned or it may also be global level instead of label level.

**Case Sensitivity** is also a point.

I have read multiple thing about **like,index,full text search,legacy index etc.**,so what will be the best fit for my case,or i have to use **elastic search** etc.

I am using **spring-data-neo4j** in my application,so provide some configuration for SDN

Answer (score 3):

Annotate your *name* with @Indexed annotation:

```
@Indexed(indexName = "whateverIndexName", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT)
private String name;
```

Then query for it following way (example for method in SDN repository, you can use similar anywhere else you use cypher):

```
@Query("START n=node:whateverIndexName({query}) return n"
Set<Topic> findByName(@Param("query") String query);
```

Neo4j uses lucene as backend for indexing so the query value must be a valid lucene query, e.g. "name:neo4j" or "name:neo4j*".

There is an article that explains the confusion around various Neo4j indexes http://nigelsmall.com/neo4j/index-confusion.

Comment: how to annotate using cypher

Comment: You can't write to legacy indexes in cypher. The only way is to setup automatic indexing. See http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to be using elastic search-- you can use the legacy indexes or the lucene indexes  to do full text searches.

Check out Michael Hunger's blog: jexp.de/blog

thix post specifically: http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/full-text-indexing-fts-in-neo4j-2-0/